# css positioning

Tags: css

What is the correct way to position something? I have a div that displays blog posts in the centre.

```
<div class="box">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <article>
  <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">      <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <h7>BY LOUIS MOORE ON</h7> <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time><?php the_content(); ?></br>    
<div class="h9"></div>
</article></br></br></br>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F1F2F2;
 border: 1.5px #D1D3D4 solid;
 border-bottom: 3px solid red;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 min-width: 90%;
}
```

I want to add 'Follow Me On Twitter', followed by a Twitter button, but I want this to be displayed on the right hand side of the div box. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
.followme {
    position: absolute;

    left:30%;
    bottom: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float: right;`

would work if you would want it within the same bounds, if you wanted it outside the box you could create a container to store them both in.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">...</div>
    <a href="#">Follow me on Twitter</a>
</div>

.contianer a {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: i want the twitter button and the text to be inside my existing div box, only just on the right rather than centred

Comment: then simply create a CSS rule to float the element

Comment: when i do that it pushes a title of my top blog out to the left a little