# What is a better way of responsive styling than CSS Position

Tags: html, css

I was wondering when styling some of my website's what the correct use of the top, right, left, bottom properties are.

This would sound like an way too open question so I am narrowing it down to this: Let's say if I am styling some text that I want at the bottom of my page would it be *correct* to use something like `bottom: 265px;`?

This would give the desired result however is this also considered clean code and a correct use of this function?

Or would there be a better option for this. I am wondering this because I also have to make my site's responsive as well.

I have had a read through [W3schools - CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [Stackoverflow Question - CSS Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142219/css-positioning) but it did not have the anwser I am looking for

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will have a read through your link (:
So basically I should almost never use positioning?

Comment: As @Paulie_D mentioned, not the thing you want: positioning ... As for the responsive part: go ahead and google some for the viewport. Think about using % instead of px. Try to use flexbox or somekind. Maybe get to know bootstrap, who knows it works for you. Start practising :) You could use W3 mobile OK and Google pagespeed insight (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) for tips on how to make the responsive design work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use top, bottom, left, and right to place absolute-positioned content.

There are certainly cases where absolute positioning is the best and cleanest approach.  The problem is that it's too easy to overuse, which can lead to very fragile layouts.

Signs that you're overusing absolute-positioning:

- every time you change something in the page you end up having to
  update a lot of absolute-positioned elements
- different content (a too-long header, or a too-short paragraph, or etc) causes things to overlap unintentionally
- your layout only works for specific screen sizes, and doesn't flow to match the browser window width

It's almost always better to start by letting the browser do most of the work, depend on document flow to position the majority of the content, and reserve absolute positioning for only the elements that really truly need to be in exactly the same place no matter what else is going on on the page.  In practice, most of the time, this tends to be relatively few (or no) elements.